# Dependency Injection in library in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Lets say I have a `CustomClass` class from a library that does somethings with a `IWebHostEnvironment` service. And I wish to create and use this library inside a `PageModel` like shown below:

```
public class CustomClass
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public CustomClass(IWebHostEnvironment environment){
        _environment = environment
    }
    public printEnvironment(){
        Console.WriteLine(_environment.ContentRootPath);
    }
}
```

- 

```
public class Index : PageModel
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public Index(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var cc = new CustomClass(environment);
        cc.printEnvironment()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write this `CustomClass` where it will automatically have access to the `IWebHostEnvironment` without me having to inject it from the `PageModel`?

I know this doesn't make much sense. The reason I'm asking this is because I'm upgrading a WebApp from `.NET Framework`, where dependency injections weren't a thing, to `.NET Core`.

Comment: It s kind of a native thing in aspnetcore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you must register this class of yours

```cs
// if you go without interface directly DI can instantiate your type
services.AddTransient(typeof(CustomClass));

// With interface will look like
services.AddTransient<ISomeInterface, CustomClass>();
// for this ^^ your class must be declared as 
public class CustomClass : ISomeInterface .......


// THEN

public class CustomClass
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public CustomClass(IWebHostEnvironment environment){
        _environment = environment
    }
    public printEnvironment(){
        Console.WriteLine(_environment.ContentRootPath);
    }
}

public class Index : PageModel
{

    private readonly CustomClass _customClass; 

    public Index(CustomClass customClass)
    {
        _customClass = customClass;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        //var cc = new CustomClass(environment); // no more needed
        _customClass.printEnvironment()
    }
}

// with interface will look like this
public class Index : PageModel
{
    private readonly ISomeInterface _customClass; 

    public Index(ISomeInterface customClass)
    {
        _customClass = customClass;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        
        _customClass.printEnvironment()
    }
}
```

Bottom line here is  - if your dependency injection knows how to get `IWebHostEnvironment`, merely registering your class like

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(CustomClass));
```

or

```
services.AddTransient<ISomeInterface, CustomClass>();
```

will be enough to DI inject implementation of `IWebHostEnvironment` into your custom class

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! But just to ask. Is this method possible if you have a constructor where you have to add other parameters that aren't dependency injections to the CustomClass? Like `public CustomClass(bool foo, IWebHostEnvironment environment) { }`

Comment: @Graf123456 I don't think so. Imagine this - DI engine is like a registry where. It grabs your class, identifies constructor parameters and it knows other registered types that might match. Keep in mind. ASP.net DI provided by framework is pretty **basic** one and it automatically registers all the controllers and some other classes from the framework. But if you set DI yourself using something like **ninject**, it has  many more construction options available and you can do things as you describe. However, asp.net framework does not use ninject. I love ninject. Check it out